# Why does my html table 'max-width' not cause text to wrap?

Tags: html, css

I have an html table and one column (or `<td>`) contains very long words. I want to set the max-width of the column so that if text is longer than the max-width the text should auto-wrap to next line. I have tried to set the css `max-width` style on the appropriate `<td>` element with `"max-width:100px"`, but it does not work.  The text is still very long and does not auto-wrap to next line.

Any ideas what is wrong or any solution reference code? I am using IE 8 on Windows 7.

Comment: As specified in [css 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths):

"In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to add the CSS3 property [`word-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap).

Comment: @George2 This css property is meant to allow a long word to be broken. If it does solve your issue, it looks like your question was missing a point: your text is not merely long, but also contains very long words.

Comment: I copyedited the question to make it clear that the text contained long words, not just long text.

Comment: I add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the style of `table`, and `max-width` to the `td` element. It works in Chrome but not in IE8: the long word is still on one line. Any suggestions?

Comment: @duskat: [IE8 fails on `max-width` in several elements](http://google.com/search?q=ie8+max-width+table+cell). Use `width` instead.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for pointing out the IE8 issue, I used `table-layout: fixed` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can put a div inside your table cells.

Nothing within that div will stretch out the table cell.

Works great in IE8 and Chrome at least.

Comment: In case of long words, adding word-wrap: break-word; will be required. In case of fixed width tables, the cell inner content may still be wider than the max-width specified on the div, but the text will be wrapped according to the div width, resulting in a loss of space. So your solution is imho limited to non-fixed width tables.

Answer (score 2):

Old html td width will work in IE 8 for that... But you want maximum-width, not a width... besides the extra html attribute needed for each cell.

Comment: "But you want maximum-width, not a width" -- what I need is simple, just make long text automatically wrap to next line, similar to automatic-wrap feature of notepad. Any solutions?

Comment: Yep, and the solution given by someone above will do. (Gotta check on IE8 , as I guess is your target) Obviously, css3 wont apply in IE6,for sure. My solution works, but is not flexible, you need fixed width on tds and probably also on the table. Which is no fun. 
break-word that he mentioned is the only way if what you try to break is words, older css properties wont break for example long registry key strings with no spaces. Anyway, older css to do wrapping:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html
(browsers support table)

Comment: Another solution I've used sometimes is embed inside a div, or span (with display:block or not, depending on what is needed), to which I apply whicever properties... can be the trick, in some cases.

Comment: About IE6, as many still uses it, its an outdated browser. I have personally blocked out Ie6 users from my sites where i cannot use time to make fixes for Ie6 users.. its time they update :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<td nowrap="wrap" style="width:100px;"></td>
```

All browsers..

Unfortunately you have to handle each cells content to keep the whole table fixed width. There is a width attribute for  but it doesn't control anything..